# QcomboBox using "ENTER" event

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, qcombobox

[image]

in this user selects item from DROP DOWN  menu use "SEARCH" button to search. I want to add "ENTER" but as a shortcut for this event. Please refer image.it will be more clear.

Comment: explain yourself better, the image does not help, you want it to happen when the user presses enter.

Comment: when i use return pressed,its throwinh this error "AttributeError: 'QComboBox' object has no attribute 'returnPressed'

Comment: exactly@eyllanesc. want it to happen when user presses "Enter" from keyboard.

Comment: and that's right, QComboBox does not have a signal to returnPressed. please provide a [mcve]

Comment: you want that when the focus is on the QComboBox and the enter key is pressed, it emits a signal. I am right?

Comment: then any other way to achieve it?

Comment: What I have indicated is correct? Your explanation is not very clear, so I am pointing out what I understand, tell me if what I think is correct.

Comment: your understanding is correct. Please go ahead with your solution.

Comment: see my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to use a `QShortcut` as I show below:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        lay = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        combo = QtGui.QComboBox()
        combo.addItems(["option1", "option2", "option3"])
        lay.addWidget(combo)
        lay.addWidget(QtGui.QPushButton("Press Me"))

        shortcut = QtGui.QShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence(QtCore.Qt.Key_Return), combo, activated=self.onActivated)

    def onActivated(self):
        print("enter pressed")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This will also trigger when the QComboBox doesn't have the focus, which might not be desired in a bigger UI with many other widgets.

Comment: @Jeronimo If you want to establish a policy on the scope of the shortcut you must establish the property [`context`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qshortcut.html#context-prop).

Comment: Ah I see. So if you set the context to `Qt::WidgetWithChildrenShortcut`, it should behave as expected.

Comment: @Jeronimo It should be, the best way to know is to try. Qt offers different types of QShorcut scopes since there are shorcuts with scope locals and other global ones. That's the advantage of using a library as mature as Qt.